# Volume Shell Integration of $\int_{0}^{1} 2\pi\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question on the integration of the below integral. It is part of a larger problem about using shell integration to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis, where 
$$y = e^{-x^2}, y=0, x=0, x=1 $$

Let $u = e^{x^2}, du = 2xe^{x^2}$
$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} 2\pi\frac{x}{e^{x^2}} = 2\pi \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} \frac{du}{u^2} \\
&= \pi \bigg[ -\frac{1}{u^1} \bigg]_{0}^{1} = \pi \bigg[ -\frac{1}{e^{2^x}} \bigg]_{0}^{1} \\
& = -\pi \frac{1}{e}
\end{align}$$

However the textbook says the answer is $\pi(1-\frac{1}{e})$. Not really sure if I set the problem up wrong, or if I did some illegal u-substitution moves (I don't feel the best about getting the $\frac{1}{u^2}$ part).

Comment: $e^0=1{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you Clayton. So that is the issue and not my u-substitution?

Comment: You have a few typos in your math code but the extra $1$ comes from plugging in $x=0$.

Comment: Correct; as @quarague points out, you have a few typos, but the only major mistake you have is assuming that plugging in $0$ produces $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup for the shell method looks fine, but the antiderivative for $\displaystyle\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx$ that you came up with doesn't seem to be correct. Just use the u-substitution $u=-x^2$:

$$
\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx=
-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-x^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(-x^2\right)\,dx=
-\frac{1}{2}\int e^u\,du=\\
-\frac{1}{2}e^u+C=
-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}+C.
$$

$$
V=2\pi\int_{0}^{1} xe^{-x^2}\,dx=
-\pi\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}\bigg|_{0}^{1}=
-\pi\left(\frac{1}{e^{1^2}}-\frac{1}{e^{0^2}}\right)=\\
-\pi\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{1}\right)=
-\pi\left(\frac{1}{e}-1\right)=
\pi\left(1-\frac{1}{e}\right)\ cubic\ units.
$$